# How to extract tar files to destination directory?

Tags: perl, tar

I'm trying to write a script which gets a path to a tar file, checking if there is a txt file in it, and if yes, extract the file to an output folder.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Archive::Tar;
use File::Spec::Functions qw(catdir);

#checking if tar file contain a txt file, if yes extract it to a folder

my $tarPath    = 'path/to/tarArchive';
my $tar        = Archive::Tar->new($tarPath);
my @files      = $tar->list_files;
my $output_dir = 'C:/output/path';
foreach my $file (@files) {
    if ( $file =~ /txt$/ ) {
        my $extracted_file = catdir( $fileName,   $file );
        my $extracted_path = catdir( $output_dir, $file );
        $tar->extract( $extracted_file, $output_dir );
        print $extracted_file;

    }
}
exit 0;
```

I'm getting an error: `no such file in archive.`

Could you please help me understand what am I doing wrong and what should be the correct command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Archive::Tar](http://perldoc.perl.org/Archive/Tar.html) `extract` method does not allow you to specify an output directory; it only allows a list of input files.  You need to use the `extract_file` method:

```
    $tar->extract_file($extracted_file, $output_dir);
```